# Alternative solution for the given problem

Tags: sql, while-loop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I asked the following question a few days back:
[Repeating the data after a particular time period](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72136861/18091145)

I got the following code in answer:

```
execute immediate 
$$
declare
   num_loops number := 10; --set the number of loops you want to iterative and create data for 
   min_day number := 1; --filter for starting range from 1 to 3
   max_day number := 3; --filter for ending range from 1 to 3
   day_increase := 3; -- each day we want to add three new days 
   day_incrementer := 3; -- we need to keep track of what value we are currently on 
   insert_stmt varchar;
begin
    let counter := 1;
   
    while (counter < num_loops) do
    
    insert_stmt :=  
        'INSERT INTO CITY_DATA              
          SELECT  DAY +' ||  :day_increase || ', ITEM_CLASS, CITY, CUTOFF, TRANSFER FROM CITY_DATA          
          WHERE DAY BETWEEN ' || :min_day || ' and ' || max_day;
         execute immediate :insert_stmt;
         day_incrementer := day_incrementer + day_increase;
          min_day := min_day + day_increase;
          max_day := max_day + day_increase;
          counter := counter + 1;
            
    end while;
    return counter || ' number of batches inserted with ending value of: ' || :day_incrementer;
end;
$$;
```

how do I run this code? I am getting continuous errors as "invalid identifier: num_loops" or unexpected

I am having hard time using this code, can anybody explain this or have an alternate answer to the above problem attached in the link.

Comment: I tested the code on SnowSQL, classic UI and Snowsight, and it worked on all.

Comment: thanks @GokhanAtil - can you mark the the original and this thread as answered if it solved your problem? thank you!